# Populating a parameter using arrays - Beginner

Tags: node.js

I am stuck with this issue for a few days now. I am not able to format the values according to the given format.

I have 2 Array objects.

```
var name = ["sam","Anthony"];
var age = ["4","10"];
```

The `name` and `age` array may contain more values in it. So it means that the 2 arrays above are dynamic.

I need to extract values from these arrays and add them in the `Item` section as shown in the following code. However, I am not able to hardcode the array content as this array is dynamic in size. It may contain more student records in it. In that case How am I able to construct the following `params` variable after populating the values of the `name` and `age` arrays ?

```
var params = {
    RequestItems: {
        "Student": [ 
            {  
                PutRequest: {
                    Item: {
                        "name": "sam",
                        "age": "4"

                    }
                }
            }, 
            { 
                PutRequest: {
                    Item: {
                        "name": "Anthony",
                        "age": "10"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `map` function:

```js
var names = ["sam", "Anthony"];
var age = ["4", "10"];

var params = {
  RequestItems: {
    "Student": names.map(function(c, index) {
      return {
        PutRequest: {
          Item: {
            "name": c,
            "age": age[index]
          }
        }
      };
    })
  }
};
alert(JSON.stringify(params, null, 4));
```